# geom_text positions per group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `geom_line`, `geom_point`, and `geom_text` to plot something like the picture below:

[image]

I am grouping, and coloring my data frame, but I want the `geom_text` not to be so close to each other.
I want to put the one text on top, and the other on bottom. Or at least, hide the one of the two. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: As far as I know, unless you are into manually tuning the positions, `FField` might be the best semi-automated solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996538/dynamic-position-for-ggplot2-objects-especially-geom-text

Comment: any way of providing an array to `hjust` `vjust`? (according to the number of groups..)

Comment: No, there's no facility for providing multiple values to hjust and vjust. In addition to the question linked above, there is also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7611169/324364) similar question, with many of the same options mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify custom aesthetics in different `geom_text()` calls. You can include only a subset of the data (such as just one group) in each call, and give each `geom_text()` a custom `hjust` or `vjust` value for each subset.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=mygroups, color=mygroups, label=mylabel)) +
geom_point() + 
geom_line() + 
geom_text(data=dat[dat$mygroups=='group1',], aes(vjust=1)) + 
geom_text(data=dat[dat$mygroups=='group2',], aes(vjust=-1))
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do! Thanks!

Comment: @Paschalis Note that while this is clever, it will only work in limited circumstances: if all points in each group have the same relative position to each other. i.e. all points in group 1 are above each corresponding point in group 2.